# Using a `@ViewChild` in a template binding throws an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

Repro: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjxytd?file=src%2Fmain.ts

I'm trying to use a **dynamic** `@ViewChild` field in an `*ngIf` binding, but the mere act of mentioning it in a template throws ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError, for example:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  standalone: true,
  template: '',
})
class Child {
  id = 'child';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [Child, CommonModule],
  template: `    
    <child></child>
    <h1 *ngIf='child'>Hello!</h1>    
  `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild(Child) child: Child | undefined;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this construct? Maybe there is a way to get your desired result without relying on ViewChild?

Comment: @cloned I want to pass a reference to one (dynamically inserted inside an ngIf) child component to another within the template - in this example ngIf is a stand-in for a property binding in a second component

Comment: Your stackblitz link doesn't even start the project (because you forgot to export class Child).

Comment: Here is the corrected version of your repro, and there are no error messages: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xdeqpy?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Thanks @OZ_ ... is there any benefit over using this instead of using services to handle the data?

Comment: Sorry, rephrase the question please, @cloned .

Comment: Is there any advantage of using this approach of using ViewChild instead of using a service to store and handle the data? I guess it depends on what the usecase is?